# Angular post formdata and file not in input

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular 1.5.

I have to call a service which need FormData :

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('files', []);
    fd.append(name, data);

    return $http.post(API + uri, fd, {
           transformRequest: angular.identity,
           headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
```

My problem is I have to join a file I have uploaded through an API. The file is not uploaded by the user.

How can I declare the file variable ?

```
var file = $http.get('api/getFile' ...); ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of vague, but I think you want something like this?

You need to get the response from the GET request in the `then` callback and in that callback you can then send the POST request. The return value of $http.get and $http.post are [promises](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/), not the response.

```
$http.get("api/getFile")
    .then(function(response) {
        var file = response.plain();
        // do stuff with file and fd ..
        $http.post(API + uri, fd, {
           transformRequest: angular.identity,
           headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .then(function(response){
            // do things with response from POST
        });
    });
```